# Read Google Maps Autocomplete inside table

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, html-table, autocomplete

I have a trip/toll calculating page where the user enters an origin, a destination and waypoints to stop by. I have managed to dynamically insert the input texts in a table using JS/Jquery and assign them to Google Maps Autocomplete. Everything is fine and working until here.

I can add/delete/sort the rows and the [Google Autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nblAp.png) works fine on all inputs. I also made some foreach loop to get each of the rows of the table and then try to read the autocomplete value out of it, but all I can get is the input value, not the Autocomplete values.

```
$('#tblInterm > tbody  > tr').each(function ()
{
    console.log(this.closest('input').val());
});
```

The point is that this table can be dragged and sorted the way the user wants to, so the order of the waypoints can and will be changed (pretty much like Google Maps itself).

What I need is a way of reading each of the inputs/autocompletes in the table to get the LatLng informations and calculate the trip/tolls based on user's inputs.

```js
//Searchs limited to Brazil only
var options = {
  componentRestrictions: {
    country: 'br'
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  //Make the table  sortable
  $("#tblInterm tbody").sortable({
    items: "> tr",
    appendTo: "parent",
    helper: "clone"
  }).disableSelection();

  //Add initial row to table
  Add();
});

//Array of waypoints and quantity control
var parada = [];
var p = 1;

//Add new waypoints
function Add() {
  //Create a input
  var inputParada = $('<input/>', {
    id: 'txtParada' + p,
    class: 'form-control',
    type: 'search',
    style: 'margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; ',
    placeholder: 'Endereço de parada'
  });

  //Insert a line in the table with the input and the delete an the add buttons
  var tr = $('<tr/>');
  tr.append('<td style="width: 80%; height: 26px; padding: 3px 0; ">' + inputParada[0].outerHTML + '</td>');
  tr.append('<td style="width: 20px; height: 20px; padding: 4px; "><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSFAG1e-_hfzLhssYiBssNc2JNBrL0aihBIavwXkGpAcrG_UfpV" class="btnDelete" height="20px"/></td>');
  tr.append('<td style="width: 20px; height: 20px; padding: 4px; "><img src="https://www.ipuc.org.co/ImagenesFuentes/iVista_Pack/PNG/Alarm/Plus.png" class="btnAdd" height="18px"/></td>');

  //Append the row to the table
  $('#tblInterm tbody').append(tr);

  //Bind delete event
  $(".btnDelete").unbind('click');
  $(".btnDelete").bind('click', Delete);

  //Bind add event
  $(".btnAdd").unbind('click');
  $(".btnAdd").bind('click', Add);

  //Make the input a Autocomplete field
  inputParada.click(function() {
    var autoParada = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById($(this)[0].id), options);
  }).click();

  //Track the amount of created rows
  p++;
}

//Delete the row
function Delete() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <table id="tblInterm" class="table table-hover">
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What I'm exactly using to get the inputs values insie the table
`$('#tblInterm > tbody > tr').each(function (i, row) { var c = row.cells[0].children[0]; });`

Comment: I don't see any attempt at getting the values in the code you posted. And you said you want to get the lat/lng information but you are not setting them anywhere! Did you read a bit on how the Autocomplete works? There is ample documentation, examples and tutorials around.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#get_place_information